Gallery Card Automation in manychat through zapier
So i am working on a instagram dm automation where i wish to showcase products as gallery cards. I am currently using zapier to fetch the products data from my wix store using a webhook block, then transforming those into the format that the official documentation wants using the code by zapier block.
The documentation that im following is (Dynamic message documentation for instagram)
Theres a manychat block in zapier with the action called “send dynamic message” which takes in the user id and the json in the format that this documentation has asked to write it in. However, no matter what i do it just wouldnt let my json pass through. The ERROR i keep getting is Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'errors')

Heres the json that my code was returning which kept giving the error:
{
  "version": "v2",
  "content": {
    "type": "instagram",
    "messages": [
      {
        "type": "cards",
        "elements": [
          {
            "title": "Card title",
            "subtitle": "card text",
            "image_url": "https://manybot-thumbnails.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ca/xxxxxxzzzzzzzzz.png",
            "action_url": "https://manychat.com",
            "buttons": []
          }
        ],
        "image_aspect_ratio": "horizontal"
      }
    ],
    "actions": [],
    "quick_replies": []
  }
}


this is currently the same json thats written in the documentation and it wont even let me use this one let alone the one i created through the transformation (which was way longer so i didnt paste it here) but both are getting the same error

This sounds like a really interesting thing that you are trying to do.  I had a look at the JSON you provided and I am guessing that it may not be fully fleshed out and was only meant as a rough example.  In particular, ManyChat may not like the empty arrays.  I would suggest fleshing things out a bit more like this:
  "version": "v2",
  "content": {
    "type": "instagram",
    "messages": [
      {
        "type": "cards",
        "elements": [
          {
            "title": "Sample Product",
            "subtitle": "This is a sample card showcasing a product.",
            "image_url": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.png&text=Sample+Image",
            "action_url": "https://example.com/product",
            "buttons": [
              {
                "type": "web_url",
                "url": "https://example.com/product",
                "title": "View Product"
              },
              {
                "type": "web_url",
                "url": "https://example.com/cart",
                "title": "Add to Cart"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "image_aspect_ratio": "horizontal"
      }
    ],
    "actions": [
      {
        "type": "web_url",
        "url": "https://example.com/shop",
        "title": "Visit Shop"
      }
    ],
    "quick_replies": [
      {
        "title": "More Products",
        "payload": "MORE_PRODUCTS"
      },
      {
        "title": "Contact Support",
        "payload": "CONTACT_SUPPORT"
      }
    ]
  }
}

See if that works for a start.  If it does, you should be on the right track and can continue to get your real data into a shape that emulates this.
If you are still having trouble please feel free to reach out using our contact form when you are logged in (https://zapier.com/app/get-help). We will be more than happy to work with you and dig into our detailed logs to see if we can find anything helpful beyond the error message you are seeing.
Ted - Zapier Support
